Getting continous data from a usb-device (looping a command to the usb-device)
Im working on a app to access a datalogger via smartphone. it has a meter mode where it displays the current measurements. now i want these measurements to update every 3 seconds, but every loop i could think of wouldnt work (ended up crashing the project). I could add code here, but i think that would be too much for this question. (im using the usb-serial library from Mike3y on GitHub to talk to the usb device)
so im putting it down in one question: is there something special i have to look for when trying to read the usb-device with a loop?
i hope it is answerable without having a specific code example. if it is necessary i can provide the code and/ or specific data for the usb-device (baud rate, reaTimeout etc.)
thanks in advance!
